# Machine learning for non optimal behaviour

Tags: machine-learning, american-options, swaption

I was working on the pricing of complex bermudean swaption when I noticed that the exercise is often (very) subobptimal. It seems that the clients are more sensitive to past growth or drop in rates than to their value at the moment.

I am looking for a way to modelise the suboptimal behaviour and I tought about Machine learning. But I can't find any reference on suboptimal options exercice.

Do you have any broader exemple of Machine learning applied to the replication of human non optimal behaviour ?

edit: Well, I have a little background in ML ([Finished Andrew Ng course](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml) on Coursera and currently going trough [ESLII](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) at a great pace). I know there is a lot of applications (see [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/projects2013.html) for tons of exemple).  I have played a bit with some basic algorithm and my data. I have some interesting results but also things to investigate. My question was more about quantitative finance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too broad, but I there is plenty of examples of uses of machine learning to mimic human behaviour. For instance deep learning has been used 25 years ago to [read checks in bank](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/lenet/index.html)s, or [support vector machines](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67119/svmtutorial.pdf) 15 years ago to implement artificial vision, or [bayesian networks to mimic expert diagnosis](http://www.aut.upt.ro/~curiac/10.pdf).

I guess it would not be that hard to use machine learning in your case if you can implement **supervised learning**. It mean you should have a database of human decision $D$ associated with the product $P$ and the market context $C$.
Then your goal will be to emulate the function:
$$D=F(P,C)+\varepsilon.$$
Of course (as usual in machine learning), you will need to focus on pre-processing to be sure the characteristics of the product and the market context are mixed in $F$ a convenient way.

Then you will have to choose a class of model ; it is difficult to help you at such an early stage since a description of the variables and the number of data are needed. Nevertheless I gave details on [Artificial Neural Networks on quant.stackexchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/multilayer-perceptron-neural-network-for-time-series-prediction/3816#3816).

**Edit:**

1. you should look after credit scoring. It models the way a consumer will be risky for a credit.
2. Neural networks are usually good to estimate a probability. It comes from the fact that if you train them on a database with 0 or 1 as outputs (for you, will be the observation of an exercise or not), they end up with a real between 0 and 1, i.e. the probability of an exercice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe a bit broad. (see my edit). I will look at your last link a bit deeper tomorrow as DNN may be sufficient for what I wanted to do. Would you say that DNN can account for (non-linear ?) lags in the market ? Or is this 'just' a NN on a moving windows ?

Comment: Basically: the output take positive values some time after there is a drop on client rates. The lag between the drop and thechange in output depends on the size of the drop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that machine learning would lead to any practical solutions here. Do you really have enough data for that kind of techniques?

I would suggest a different approach: assume that the exercise is optimal, but just based on a different cost function than the expected pay-off. If you can find a function that replicates well enough the past exercise decisions, maybe you can use it to predict the future ones.

Comment: >  If you can find a function that replicates well enough the past exercise decisions...

Well that is the point of machine learning...